# Is there a way in `lxml` to skip irrelevant branches when parsing

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

I am attempting to parse small amounts of data from a large XML file (2G).

For small files I would just use

```
root_node.xpath('/the/specific/path/i/am/interested/in')
```

but I have read that this is very memory consuming.

For large files, [this reference](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-hiperfparse/index.html) suggests the methods of implementing a **target parser** or using `etree.iterparse`.
Although less memory consuming, these methods still iterate over the whole tree.

Can `lxml` also be used to skip iterating through all irrelevant branches, i.e. avoiding the parser to enter them?

For example when I have

```
<the>
  <irrelevant_to_me> 3000 lines, do not enter! </irrelevant_to_me>
  <specific>
    <irrelevant_to_me> 3000 lines, do not enter! </irrelevant_to_me>
    <path>
      <irrelevant_to_me> 3000 lines, do not enter! </irrelevant_to_me>
      <i>
         <irrelevant_to_me> 3000 lines, do not enter! </irrelevant_to_me>
         <am>
         <irrelevant_to_me> 3000 lines, do not enter! </irrelevant_to_me>
           <interested>
             <irrelevant_to_me> 3000 lines, do not enter! </irrelevant_to_me>
             <in>
               <!-- goal -->
             </in>
           </interested>
         </am>
      </i>
    </path>
  </specific>
</the>
```

The parser should not even enter the `<irrelevant_to_me>`-Nodes (regardless of their name).

Comment: Did you try and run actually run into memory problems or are you just intimidated by the warnings? You also did not mention, whether you actually need to modify that huge file; if not, switching from lxml to SAX would be an option.

Comment: @guidot I did not verify it but I am quite sure. Also independent from the actual memory load, I have a didactical interest in the more adaptive approach of using parsers. Due to dependency constraints of my actual project I would strongly prefer an `lxml`-based solution.